# Rails Associations - Strong Parameters Build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

So I have to following models.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :players
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :statistics
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

I wish to build a team that has players, these will be selected by the user. I can do this perfectly in the console by doing to following.

```
@user = User.find(10) 
@team = @user.build_team(name: "MyTeam", points: 0)
    #<Team team_id: nil, name: "MyTeam", points: 0, user_id: 10>
@team.players.build(name: "Messi") 
    #<Player player_id: nil, name: "Messi", role: nil>
@team.save
```

However I am really struggling passing parameters due to strong params. Here is my view

```
<%= form_for :team do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :players do |players| %>
        <%= players.label :player_name %>
        <%= players.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>

    <div><%= f.submit "Create Team" %></div>

<% end %>
```

I want to build the team using the team parameters and the players using the player parameters, however I cannot figure out how to get this working in the controller.

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new 
    end

    def create 
         @user = User.find(current_user.id)
         @team = @user.build_team(team_params) #Just the team paramaters 

         @team = @team.players.build(player_params)# I want just the player params 

         @team.save
    end

private

    # I can add the player param as nested i.e. .permit(:name, :players => [:name])
    # but then build_team complains about receiving an array. 

    def team_params
        params.require(:team).permit(:name) 
    end

end
```

Any solutions welcome, as are any improvements.

**EDIT - ADDED SCHEMA**

```
create_table "players", primary_key: "player_id", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name", limit: 50, null: false
    t.string "role", limit: 30, null: false
end

create_table "players_teams", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "player_id", null: false
    t.integer "team_id",   null: false
end

# players_teams is a Composite Primary Key, as instructed in the guides;
# also essential for targeting. 

create_table "teams", primary_key: "team_id", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name",    limit: 200,             null: false
    t.integer "points",              default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "user_id",                         null: false
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Since this has not yet been answered I'll add more explanation as to what I am attempting.

The user has one team, I can build the team and the relationship is also built thanks to ActiveRecord. The users team then has many players and players have many teams, when I try to build this relationship the players table never changes, no relationship is created.

I feel I should stress again that the following works perfectly in the rails console

```
@user = User.find(10) 
@team = @user.build_team(name: "MyTeam", points: 0)
    #<Team team_id: nil, name: "MyTeam", points: 0, user_id: 10>
@team.players.build(name: "Messi") 
    #<Player player_id: nil, name: "Messi", role: nil>
@team.save
```

Team is set to accept nested parameters so I thought this would work.

```
@team = @user.build_team(team_params)

def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:name, players_attributes: [:name, :role]) 
end
```

I believe this should build the players model and create the relationship however no player is ever inserted and no relationship built.

Comment: Can you share schema of `teams` and `players` table from `schema.rb`. Add it to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First make a few changes in the `TeamsController` as below:

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new 
      ## Set "@team" and build "players"
      @team = current_user.build_team
      @team.players.build
    end

    def create 
      @team = current_user.build_team(team_params)  
      if @team.save
        ## Redirect to teams show page 
        redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' 
      else
        ## In case of any error while saving the record, renders the new page again 
        render action: 'new'
      end
    end

   private

    # I can add the player param as nested i.e. .permit(:name, :players => [:name])
    # but then build_team complains about receiving an array. 

    def team_params
      ## Permit players_attributes
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, players_attributes: [:id, :name]) 
    end

end
```

After this, update the view as below:

```
<%# Changed "form_for :team" to "form_for @team" %>
<%= form_for @team do |f| %> 

    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :players do |player| %> <%# Changed "|players|" to "|player|" %>
        <%= player.label :name %>  <%# Changed "player_name" to "name" and "players" to "player" %>
        <%= player.text_field :name %> <%# Changed "players" to "player" %>
    <% end %>

    <div><%= f.submit "Create Team" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Set an instance variable `@team` in `new` action and build the players for that `@team`.
Use `@team` instance variable as an argument for `form_for` in your view code.

I have also suggested a few tweaks in the `create` action, so you know if the team is saved or not.
And fixed the `team_params` method to permit the nested attributes of `players`.

**UPDATE**

Using `@team` as an argument to `form_for` method is resource-oriented style and much preferred way. 
Read this pretty good description about [usage of form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) to get a better idea. 
You can still implement the required code while using `:team` but its *not preferred way* of doing it.

Example using `:team`:

```
<%= form_for :team do |f| %> 

    <%# ... %>

    <%= f.fields_for :players, f.object.players.build do |player| %> <%# build the players for the team %>
        <%# ... %>
    <% end %>

    <%# ... f.submit "Create Team" %>

<% end %>
```

`fields_for` in your case would iterate over players (`@team.players`) belonging to a particular team (`@team`). If there are no players then you won't see any fields for players in the form, which is why you build the players so you at least get some blank fields for players to input which is why when using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you need to build the nested attributes. You can build them either at controller level(as shown in above suggested code) or within the form.

Example for "within the form":

```
<%= form_for @team do |f| %> 

    <%# ... %>

    <%= f.fields_for :players, @team.players.build do |player| %> <%# build the players for @team %>
        <%# ... %>
    <% end %>

    <%# ... f.submit "Create Team" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't add the players to the team.

Comment: @JamesParker Let me know what problem you are facing. Can you share the server log generated upon form submission after making the suggested changes.

Comment: Why down vote? At least put a reason for down voting.

Comment: I can't downvote, not enough points. So it wasn't me :) I'll have a read about and if I still come up stuck, I'd be grateful for a chat.

Comment: @JamesParker Please share the server log generated upon form submission after making the suggested changes. It will be easy to debug then.

Comment: I played about with what you gave me and finally got it working. It seems that using the `@team` in the form made the difference; also building the instance in the new method. Could you possibly explain to me why this works?

Comment: @JamesParker Please read the UPDATE section in my answer. I have added additional points to clarify your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd just do the nested attributes at once which will create the players through nested attributes e.g.

```
def create 
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
     @team = @user.build_team(team_params)
     @team.save
end

def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:name, :players => [:name]) 
end
```

If you're desperate to seperate them you should be able to do something like

```
def player_params
  params.require(:team).permit(:name, :players => [:name])[:team][:players]
end
```

I.e. you're going to have to filter out just the players parameters

Comment: Using the first method produces the error about it receiving an array. Also I don't think that would build the association between the team and players. The second solution complains "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: It'll be something like the second, what does this `params.require(:team).permit(:name, :players_attributes => [:name])` contain?

Comment: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "team"=>{"name"=>"MyTeam",
 "players"=>{"name"=>"Messi"}},
 "commit"=>"Create Team"}` The new method actually errors by saying `unknown attribute: players
`

Comment: Ok, make it players rather than players_attributes

Comment: It already is players rather than players_attributes. The error says that the attribute players is not known, not the players_attribute. Confusing to read ;)

Comment: Then use players_attributes

Comment: players_attributes is recognised however, still not working. `Mysql2::Error: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO 'players' VALUES ("MyTeam")`. For some reason it's trying to insert the team name, I've tried changing the player name column to player_name to avoid collisions. Still no luck

Comment: Try `params.require(:team).permit(:name, :players_attributes => [:name])[:team][:players]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55516/discussion-between-james-parker-and-baloo).

Answer (score 1):

As I was literally going through the same issues this weekend, I would highly recommend using a nested_form.

You can find all the implementation details here: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Answer (score 0):

You are very close with what you had.

Just add the :id field to player_attributes params and it should work for you.

```
def team_params
  params.require(:team).permit(:name, players_attributes: [:id, :name, :role]) 
end
```

You may want to check out the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem. It makes it a lot easier for handling the nested forms and allowing users to add/remove using JS.

If you also want to allow destroying, add a check box for the field _destroy on the player and add the key in players_attributes. Also update the model to allow destroying.

Model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Controller:

```
def team_params
  params.require(:team).permit(:name, players_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name, :role]) 
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.fields_for :players do |player| %> <%# Changed "|players|" to "|player|" %>
  <%= player.label :name %>  <%# Changed "player_name" to "name" and "players" to "player" %>
  <%= player.text_field :name %> <%# Changed "players" to "player" %>
  <%= player.check_box :_destroy %> Delete
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The player is never inserted into the DB and the relation is therefore never made.